# Voice commands for contacts with unusual names

Tags: voice-command, s-voice, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Device: Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

My partner's name is not "anglo" and I have not worked out a way to pronounce it and have it understood. Are there work-arounds for this?

1. Can I get the phone to pronounce the name so that I can try to use the same tortured pronunciation?
2. Is there a way to set a simpler "nick name" for a contact that can be better understood?
3. On my device, can Google Now do the same thing instead of S-Voice I.e. "Call partner_name/nickname" and would it be any better?

Comment: Number 1. would be my first try, too. Just put the name in some text, and use TTS to have Android speak it. There are plenty of TTS apps available on Playstore; a tiny free app like [Auto Speak Clipboard 2](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Auto-Speak-Clipboard-2/com.chungsdoors.android.asc2) should do fine in your case. I don't know about 2. (never tried), and can't tell about 3. (have no Sammy Note).

Comment: Well, @Izzy thanks - that worked! I installed Auto Speak Clipboard 2, heard the tortured way it pronounces my partner's name, replicated that and experienced the exquisite dichotomy of having something *finally* work while being extremely embarrassed at having spoken a beautiful name as though my mouth were full of banana peels. If you put this as a separate answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Done! Glad it solved that easy. And next time remember which part of the bananas to eat and which part to throw away – sounds you've had it the wrong way around ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the first approach, and have the system pronounce the name. To do so, a simple TTS app like [Auto Speak Clipboard 2](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Auto-Speak-Clipboard-2/com.chungsdoors.android.asc2) will do: Install it, copy her name to the clipboard, send out all cats and your girl (to avoid their punishment), and have that app speak what it thinks the name should sound like. Have some Valerian ready in case you freak out ;)

Comment: Well, there is another way that helps too. Set a phonetic name: http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/06/10/tip-add-a-phonetic-name-to-contacts-voice-recognition-just-cant-get-right/ I have spent the last two hours trying to create a phonetic name that reproduces the correct pronunciation and am about to throw my brand new phone through the window. But at least I have options.. Set a phonetic nick name or contort my vooooowells unteeel aye canne pro-nunse-ee-yate her name.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram: Feel free to make it a separate answer. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. // And yes, I had my play with that part as well: convincing the German TTS to pronounce my nick correctly, I had to mis-spell it as "isi" :)

Comment: Hmm, next annoying thing: I have given a unique name as the phonetic name - no one else has that name anywhere in their records, and S Voice recognises the name.. but brings up the four contacts in my address book with her surname, so I still have to choose.

Comment: Well, as in my previous comment suggested a separate answer, I suggest a separate question here. Include a link to this one (so you don't have to repeat the entire story or duplicate background info), and describe the second issue. An example action (what you tried to accomplish, how you did it, and how S-Voice reacted (bringing up the 4 records, of which 3 should not match the phonetics if I understood correctly?)). Our site works best with one question per "page".

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to do this would be to open the contacts/people app, go to phonetic name, and use voice typing, speaking naturally, to enter it into the phonetic spelling field.